# Не работает mcrypt_module на локалке

Tags: php, denwer, mcrypt

Вот такая ошибка вылетает

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_module_open() in

php.ini редактировал - не помогло. Что делать? Сайт написан в 2000х годах не мной. Использую Денвер.

Answer (score 0):

С денвером не знаком. Использую xampp если на винде.

В `php.ini` раскоментить (убрать ; )

```
;extension=php_mcrypt.dll
extension=php_mcrypt.dll
```

Убедиться что есть `php_mcrypt.dll` в `../php5/mods-available/`

Возможно нужно указать путь к `dll` в папке `/php5/mods-enabled/` если такой нет,то в `/php5/conf.d` (в этих папках уже есть файлы, копируем меняем название на любое, внутри указываем путь до `php_mcrypt.dll`)

Перезапустить веб-сервер! (apache или nginx если там fpm)